# update input of user in map function React hooks

Tags: reactjs, web, react-hooks, frontend

New to react hooks...
I've brought some data of users from an API and I want to update one or more of the inputs by clicking a submit button.
I can see in the state that the user's last letter changes but I can see the new input on the screen and I can not change the entire word. And I don't know if it is supposed to change also in the whole array of users or it is impossible once I've called them from the API.
Thanks

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
function UsersComp() {
    const [user, setUser] = useState()
    const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
    const [id, setId] = useState(0)

    const getUsers=async ()=>{
        let resp = await axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
        setUsers(resp.data); 
    }
    
    const update = async (e) =>
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        let resp = await axios.put("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/" + id, user)
    }
 
    return (
    <div calssname="App">
        <form onSubmit={e => update(e)}>
            {
                users.map((item) =>
                {
                    return <tbody key={item.id}>
                                <tr><td>
                                    ID:{item.id} <br/>
                                    Name:<input value={item.name} onChange={e => setUser({...user, name : e.target.value})} type="text" name="name" /> <br/>
                                    Email:<input value={item.email} onChange={e => setUser({...user, email : e.target.value})} type="text" name="email" /> <br/>
                                <input type="button" value="Add Data"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
                                <input type="button" value="Delete"/><br/> 
                                </td></tr>
                    </tbody>
                })
            }
        </form>
        <input type="button" value="Get users" onClick={getUsers} /> <br/>
        
    </div>
    );
  }
  
  export default UsersComp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can update `onChange` like this by using `map`:

```
onChange={(e) =>
  setUser(
    users.map((eachUser) =>
      item.id === eachUser.id ? { ...eachUser, name: e.target.value } : eachUser,
    ),
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand. Why it doesn't let me write new data on the input space or change the existing data? What have I done wrong? Thanks again